# What do I do if the mobile interface won't let me create new tags and I'm asking a question about a new game?

Tags: support

Specifically, this question: [What is the secret of the blue bug in Your Doodles Are Bugged?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97278/what-is-the-secret-of-the-blue-bug-in-your-doodles-are-bugged)

I tried tagging the question as 'untagged' and 'tagme', so that someone else could edit and add the appropriate tag, but no joy. Eventually I just tagged it Steam.

I'm not suggesting that meta tags are a good idea in general, but in this special case they would have solved the problem.

**What other solutions could / should I have tried?**

Comment: For now, I guess you just put a trite tag on it and request a retagging in the question body.  But yeah, this is silly.

Answer (score 9):

The same advice applies here that applies to users with insufficient reputation: **If you're unable to create a new tag, use the most appropriate tag available to you, and leave a comment, a mod flag, or a request on [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) for somebody to fix it.**

In general, when in doubt, platform tags work well for these situations.

Comment: You can also just switch away from the mobile site to create a tag.

Comment: @Fluttershy True, but switching back is a pain in the ass, and thus I tend not to like bothering.

Comment: I, for one, like the original site. But maybe that's cuz I'm using an iPad.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Is there a technical reason why the Mobile site doesn't allow tag creation - or is it a policy decision to not allow Mobile users to create tags?

Comment: @Ebongo as I understand it, it's a policy decision: mobile users are assumed to be typo prone, and the limitation is meant to prevent incorrect tags.

Answer (score 3):

1. ask using wrong tag
2. switch to full site
3. retag

Comment: Had to do this today for shank 2 :-\